# How to create a FAT16 partition on an SD card with OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, partition

I want to prepare an SD card for use in an old camera using [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK). The card needs to be FAT16 formatted. This doesn’t work from Terminal anymore, maybe already for years. Disk Utility provides ''FAT'', but this is FAT32. I have no other (Windows) computer. What do I do?

Comment: How large is the SD Card? FAT16 has a nominal size limit of 2GB. `diskutil` should still be able to do FAT16 up to 2GB, I use it a lot.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### You can format any drive to FAT16 with `newfs_msdos` Command

**1) Launch Terminal**

**2) Find The Drive you Want to Format**

```
#mount
/dev/disk2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
/dev/disk4s1 on /Volumes/USB_Disk (msdos, local, nodev, nosuid, noowners)
```

In this case, my disk is disk4.  **Your disk will most likely be different!  Be sure to reference the correct disk - you can and will lose your data if you format the wrong drive!!!**

**3) Unmount the disk**

```
#diskutil unmountDisk disk4
Unmount of all volumes on disk4 was successful
```

**4)  Format the drive**

```
#sudo newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/disk4
```

After a few moments, your drive will format.

**5)  Remount the drive (optional)**

```
#diskutil mount /dev/disk4
```

It will probably show up as `"NO NAME"` on your Desktop.  You can rename it here or to do it at the time of formatting use `-v Type in a Volume Name` when you format the drive.

Comment: This results in a FAT32 formatted drive.

Comment: You can also try `newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/xxxxxx` where xxxxxx is your drive that you want to format.  Let me know if that works and I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this worked (first it gave me 'resource busy', had to unmount first).

Comment: I'll update the answer for you....

Comment: In OS X 10.8.5 I didn't have to use `sudo` to have `newfs_msdos` format my disk.  Are you saying in 10.11 it's required?  Anyway, nice directions. +1

Comment: @user3439894 I had to use it in 10.10 as well as 10.11.  I don't know if or what changed in the OS.  Thanks for the compliments.

Comment: Newbies, be mindful the `#` is _not_ part of any of the commands that you enter; it's simply this author's visual indicator of the beginning of a terminal line. My drive was also labelled `/dev/disk2s1` & I had to add `force` and also removed the `s1` from the drive name in Step 3: `diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk2`. Then, when I formatted in Step 4, I added the `s1` back again. However, when I tried `diskutil mount /dev/disk2` per Step 5, I got some sort of read error on Mac and ended up then plugging it in Windows to reformat anyway. Maybe I should've done `diskutil mount /dev/disk2s1`.

Answer (score 8):

For what it's worth, this seems to work on High Sierra:

```
diskutil eraseDisk "MS-DOS FAT16" SOMENAME /dev/disk#
```

It still needs to be unmounted first.

Comment: Hi ammulder, and welcome to ask different! On this site, it is preferred that answers explain exactly what you're doing and why it works - especially with terminal commands like this. Thanks, and happy answering!

Comment: My command looks like below, and it works: `diskutil eraseDisk "MS-DOS FAT16" "WINDOWSXP" MBR disk2`

Answer (score 6):

I spend all evening to understand how to format a USB stick to FAT16 and its so simple and just copy these commands to your terminal:

1. `diskutil unmountDisk disk4`
2. `sudo newfs_msdos -F 16 /dev/disk4`
3. `diskutil mount /dev/disk4`

This works for all sizes of drives.

**Note:** For other users: the reference to `disk4` in the commands above may need to be changed to  ensure it refers to the correct drive.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the accepted answer, except more compact, and lacking the useful `mount` command to see what drives are mounted.

Answer (score -8):

Why so hard to explain things, it is the main reason why many new users get away from linux.

Just do  mkfs.vfat -F16 /dev/sdb(x) if you want to name the USb, flash, etc... put this in addiction -n (name), then it looks like this:

mkfs.vfat -F16 /dev/sdb(x) -n (name) and hit enter.

Comment: OS X/macOS **is not** Linux and OS X/macOS doesn't have `mkfs.vfat` _command_.